# Invoking a super class method from a super class constructor

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a quite simple question regarding the following code snippet.

```
public class SuperClass {

    public SuperClass() {
        this.test();  //Always invokes the overridden method in the sub-class.
    }

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test() in SuperClass.");
    }
}

public final class SubClass extends SuperClass {

    public SubClass() {
        super();        
    }

    @Override
    public void test() {        
        System.out.println("test() in SubClass.");
    }
}

public final class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SubClass subClass=new SubClass();
    }
}
```

In this example, the only line in the `main()` method indirectly passes a call to the super class constructor in which it attempts to invoke the `test()` method as `this.test()`.

The method invoked by `this.test()` in the super class constructor is however, the **overridden** method in `SubClass`.

Why doesn't the method call `this.test()` in the super class constructor invoke its own method in the super class itself (though `this` refers to the current instance by which *this* method is to be invoked)?

Comment: Because `this` is the current `SubClass` instance.

Comment: @RohitJain: IMO it's a related, but clearly different, question.

Comment: @NPE I take your point. I shouldn't have closed it as duplicate, but that question contains the answer to this question :)

Comment: There is no `SuperClass` instance, there is only a `SubClass` instance.

Comment: @RohitJain: I agree; it does (but might be a little too involved for this question). :)

Comment: @NPE Agreed. I retracted my close vote then :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122785/polymorphic-method-in-constructor-java/9122943 for an exact dup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> though[t] `this` refers to the current instance by which this method is to be invoked

It does, and the runtime type of that instance is `SubClass`, so the `SubClass`'s method gets invoked.

Answer (score 1):

In object oriented programming, one of the ideas is that the object itself is responsible for how it operates on its data. Because you invoke a `SubClass` object, when you call `test()` on that object, from anywhere, you call SubClass's `test()` method. The `this` keyword refers to  the current instance, which will refer to whatever the object was invoked as.

Comment: It's a logical argument, but may be a little too general. For example, in C++ the equivalent code would invoke the superclass's `test()` method.

Comment: That's interesting to know. When I learned C++ I was taught to mark any method intended to be overridden as virtual so that's a behavior I've never actually seen.

Comment: Confusingly, in C++ what I described happens with `virtual` methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496440/c-virtual-function-from-constructor